# Return array of fields from subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

can anyone please help I want to query mongo to unwind the array,and i am using mongdb native driver My collection document is as follow,Also please ignore my objectId its just for sample

```
{  
      "_id":ObjectId(123),
      "name":"Sam",
      "age":20,
      "hobbiesDetail":[  
         {  
            "description":"FootBall",
            "level":"20%"
         },
         {  
            "description":"Cricket",
            "level":"80%"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "_id":ObjectId(124),
      "name":"Ted",
      "age":26,
      "hobbiesDetail":[  
         {  
            "description":"FootBall",
            "level":"20%"
         }
      ]
   }
```

And my expected output is

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Sam",
      "age":20,
      "hobbies":"Football,Cricket"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Ted",
      "age":26,
      "hobbies":"Football"
   }
]
```

I just want to unwind my array and add a comma between hobbies description in one query, Thanx for any help

Comment: I don't like your expected output how about `[ { 'name': 'Sam', 'age': 20, 'hobbies': ['Football', 'Cricket' ] }]`?

Comment: No i cant because i want this to convert to excel,In excel it is not giving proper result for arrays

Comment: I suggest you return "hobbies" as array and do the remaining work client side.

Comment: Ohk Sir thanku,how can i query to get above result you suggested,as i cant use $concat i am using mongodb 2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)ion with the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map) array operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "name": 1, 
        "age": 1, 
        "hobbies": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$hobbiesDetail", 
                "as": "hobby", 
                "in": "$$hobby.description" 
            } 
        } 
    }}
])
```

Comment: Why my hobbies  field at top [ {'hobbies': ['Football', 'Cricket' ] , 'name': 'Sam', 'age': 20 }]

Comment: i want it at last

Comment: For that do i need to add another projection stage?

Comment: @Parshuram I have the correct order. [Modify the order in which properties are displayed in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348042/modify-the-order-in-which-properties-are-displayed-in-mongodb). You can always do this since you need a client side processing. What is your language driver?

Comment: I am using nodejs,and now i am playing in robomongo its not giving me proper order as per my $project stage

Comment: @Parshuram [How to change the order of the fields in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542529/how-to-change-the-order-of-the-fields-in-json)