# I retrieved data from mongodb using pymongo but why every time fields' sequence is different in output?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

the code is:-

```
import pymongo
cur=pymongo.MongoClient()

db=cur.test1
for site in db.sites.find():
    print(site)
```

In the output, why the sequence is different everytime? It should be url first and then name as filled.
[ouput screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uJ6f.png)

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify the order in which properties are displayed in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348042/modify-the-order-in-which-properties-are-displayed-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no order in dictionaries , these are just key,value pairs so it is normal to have a different output everytime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to print the answer in the same order as inserted?