# Returns data in different order then original

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

The cursor returned from pymongo query has result in different sequence then originally stored in database. why and how to fix it.

Returned Json

```
{"ID":"123", "Remediation":"restart", "credentials":"user:pass"}
```

Expected Json (I expect credentials first)

```
{"ID":"123", **"credentials":"user:pass"**, "Remediation":"restart"}
```

code

```
client=pymongo.MongoClient()   
db=client.Mydatabase   
cursor=db.paramtable.find()   
print dir(cursor)
```

Comment: Python dict is unordered. While document in MongoDB is ordered.

Comment: At this point I only have one test element. {"ID":"123", "credentials":"user:pass", "Remediation":"restart"} and when I query this element on database the results are unchanged

Comment: I want pymongo to return data as is, no changes

Comment: The order I refered is keys order inside dict. In python,  {"ID":"123", "credentials":"user:pass", "Remediation":"restart"} ==  {"ID":"123", "Remediation":"restart", "credentials":"user:pass"}

Comment: If you want to keep original order, use `as_class=OrderedDict` option.  see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001156/how-to-get-ordered-dictionaries-in-pymongo)