# How do I copy the indexes from one collection to another collection using PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In another question ([How do I copy a collection from one database to another database on the same server using PyMongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245112/how-do-i-copy-a-collection-from-one-database-to-another-database-on-the-same-ser)) I figured out how to copy one MongoDB collection to another database on the same server. However this doesn't copy the indexes on the source collection so how do I copy those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for name, index_info in db_1.collection_x.index_information().items():
    keys = index_info['key']
    del(index_info['ns'])
    del(index_info['v'])
    del(index_info['key'])
    db_2.collection_y.create_index(keys, name=name, **index_info)
```

Answer (score 5):

So using a simplified setup as follows:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client.db1.coll1.insert({'content':'hello world'})
client.db1.coll1.create_index(keys='content')
```

We can see that this has a custom index:

```
>>> client.db1.coll1.index_information()
{u'_id_': {u'key': [(u'_id', 1)], u'ns': u'db1.coll1', u'v': 1},
 u'content_1': {u'key': [(u'content', 1)], u'ns': u'db1.coll1', u'v': 1}}
```

I then create a second collection `coll2` by copying the data as follows:

```
client.db1.coll1.aggregate([{'$out':'coll2'}])
```

The following then appears to work for copying the index:

```
for name, index_info in client.db1.coll1.index_information().iteritems():
    client.db1.coll2.create_index(keys=index_info['key'], name=name)
```

I was concerned that since `coll2` would already have a primary key index '_id', this might cause an error but it appears to have worked just like that:

```
>>> client.db1.coll2.index_information()
{u'_id_': {u'key': [(u'_id', 1)], u'ns': u'db1.coll2', u'v': 1},
 u'content_1': {u'key': [(u'content', 1)], u'ns': u'db1.coll2', u'v': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

My goodness I've been stuck on this for AGES.

Here is an updated answer that is actually working for me.

The difficult thing is getting it to work with various types of indexes. There are probably more edge cases to be handled (won't work for search indexes for sure)

Finally figured it out by reading the [create_indexes](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_indexes) pymongo documentation (duh), making use of the IndexModel operation class:

```
from pymongo import IndexModel
from pymongo.collection import Collection


def copy_indexes(from_collection: Collection, to_collection: Collection):
    """
    Copies indexes from one collection to another, including special handling for text indexes and other options.

    Args:
        from_collection: The source collection
        to_collection: The destination collection

    Returns:
        None
    """
    try:
        index_models = []
        for index in from_collection.list_indexes():

            # Skip the default _id index
            if index["name"] == "_id_":
                continue

            print(f"Copying index {index['name']}")

            # Prepare the index model
            keys = index["key"].items()
            options = {k: v for k, v in index.items() if k not in ["key", "v", "ns"]}
            index_model = IndexModel(keys, **options)
            index_models.append(index_model)

        # Create all indexes at once in the destination collection
        if index_models:
            to_collection.create_indexes(index_models)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while copying indexes: {e}")
```