# rmongodb: how to enforce field ordering by specifying in the projection query?

Tags: r, mongodb, aggregation-framework, rmongodb

I have some data I am trying to retrieve from mongodb into R using `rmongodb` package. At some point in time, the ordering of the fields in the stored documents changed.

I am trying to force my projection query to keep the order of the fields projected fixed by explicitly specifying approach attempted in: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976772/ordering-fields-from-find-query-with-projection) as follows:

```
data <- mongo.find.all(mongo_conn, table,
                          fields = list('id1' = 1, 'id2' = 2,
                                        'time' = 3, 'latitude' = 4,
                                        'longitude' = 5, '_id' = 0))
```

I can't seem to find a good answer to this. It returns the fields in the order they are in the DB, which changed, as a list of course.

That means, it wreaks obvious havoc in what kind of loopy code I have to write to organize the returned results into a data frame like structure.

Any idea how I can get the fields in specified order and not what is in DB?

Comment: [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) will be your solution I think.

Comment: Not entirely sure on what you're asking; can you provide example data and/or an expected result? Any reason why you can't do the sorting in R, and that you're not using the aggregation framework?

Comment: In the database, at some point, the order of storing the above fields in each document has changed. MongoDB is returning these fields in the order they appear in the database. I want them returned in the order I am specifying. Of course, I can re-order in R, which I am doing. But, that requires me to run through entire data (list returned) and sort each entry of list.

Comment: Also, when specifying the fields you want returned, you can only use `0` (don't return) or `1` (return).

Answer (score 1):

In the answer you link to it says

> Simple answer is that you can't do this.

Also see the [related mongodb ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12599)

However, to get your results in a `data.frame`-like structure, use [`mongolite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/index.html), it's much easier to work with

Consider this example using the **mtcars** data

```
data("mtcars")

library(mongolite)  

mongo <- mongo(db = "test",
               collection = "mtcars",
               url = "mongodb://localhost")

## insert into database
mongo$insert(mtcars)
# Complete! Processed total of 32 rows.
# [1] TRUE
```

`mongolite::find` will automatically simplify the query results into a data.frame structure

```
df_results <- mongo$find()
# Imported 32 records. Simplifying into dataframe...

head(df_results)
#                     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Or, using the aggregation framework

```
mongo$aggregate(pipeline = '[{ "$project" : { "mpg" : 1, "wt" : 1, "_id" : 0}  },
                             { "$limit" : 5 }]')

# Imported 5 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
#     mpg    wt
# 1 21.0 2.620
# 2 21.0 2.875
# 3 22.8 2.320
# 4 21.4 3.215
# 5 18.7 3.440
```

---

And now for a bit of shameless self-promotion. I've been working on an extension to mongolite that returns a data.table object.
The idea here is to increase the speed of returned objects, but only if the returned result set can be coerced using `rbindlist`.

The package is [`mongolitedt`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mongolitedt), and still in development.

```
# devtools::install_github("SymbolixAU/mongolitedt")
library(mongolitedt)

bind_mongolitedt(mongo)

mongo$aggregatedt(pipeline = '[{ "$project" : { "mpg" : 1, "wt" : 1, "_id" : 0}  },
                             { "$limit" : 5 }]')

## now have a data.table object returned
#  Imported 5 records.
#     mpg    wt
# 1: 21.0 2.620
# 2: 21.0 2.875
# 3: 22.8 2.320
# 4: 21.4 3.215
# 5: 18.7 3.440

## clean up
rm(mongo); gc()
```

Comment: @Arun - it can be improved further still, I just need learn/improve my C programming..

Comment: @Arun - also, thanks for [#1659](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1659) - I can now return the `_id` field :)